# How to get node resource reserved/capacity in Kubernetes (kubelet flags/configuration)?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

There is a documentation article [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/) explaining on how one can reserve resources on a node for system use.

What I did not manage to figure out is how can one get these values? If I understand things correctly `kubectl top nodes` will return available resources, but I would like to see `kube-reserved`, `system-reserved` and `eviction-threshold` as well.

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, check its on node's status `kubectl describe nodes $NODE_NAME` in Capacity and Allocatable section , also check the flags of kubelet

Comment: I do see Capacity and Allocatable in there, but it does not provide more info than that. How can I check the flags of kubelet?

Comment: I would also check if the kubelet is using config file or flag, which depends on the kubernetes version, but here is the link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/

Comment: I have sshed to the node but can't figure out which commands on kubelet should be called

Comment: If you have sshd , then just run `ps aufx | grep kubelet`

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick and I can see all parameters kubelet was run with including those I try to figure out. This was a bit more complicated than running a kubectl command I was hoping for :)

Comment: I found `kube-reserved` and `eviction` in there but not `system-reserved`, does it mean some default settings or rather it's being set other place than command line arguments during start?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196576/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-ilya-chernomordik).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by checking the kubelet's flag, we can get the values of kube-reserved, system-reserved and eviction-threshold.

ssh into the `$NODE` and  `ps aufx | grep kubelet` will list out the running kubelet and its flag.

kube-reserved and system-reserved values are only useful for scheduling as scheduler can see the allocatable resources.

Answer (score 1):

To see your **eviction-threshold** (evictionHard or systemReserved) after login on master node first start the kubectl proxy in the background using the following command:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8001 &
```

After that run the following command to see your desired node config (replace your node name in variable.eg VAR="worker-2")

```
VAR="NODE_NAME"; curl -sSL "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/nodes/$VAR/proxy/configz"
```

You shoul see a result look like:

> "evictionHard":{"imagefs.available":"15%","memory.available":"100Mi","nodefs.available":"10%","nodefs.inodesFree":"5%"},
>
> "systemReserved":{"cpu":"600m","memory":"0.5Gi"}

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thank you. This option helps especially if we use an AMI (bottlerocket) which does not even let us do ps.